# Finding joker numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic, prime-gaps

Let $n$ be an integer, $q(n)$ be the smallest prime number which divides $n$ and $r(n)$ be the biggest prime number less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$. We say that $n$ is joker if $q(n)=r(n)$.

Except $8$, joker numbers  are of the form $p_n\cdot p_{n+k}$, with $k\geq 0$.
The converse is obviously false.
If $(p_n)$ is the prime numbers sequence, it is easy to prove that a number of the form $p_n\cdot p_{n+k}$ is joker if and only if $p_{n+1}^2 > p_n\cdot p_{n+k}$. In particular, if a number is not joker for $k$, it is not joker for $k+1$ (with the same $n$).
So, all the numbers of the form $p_n^2$ and $p_n\cdot p_{n+1}$ are jokers.
Using a spreadsheet, we can see that for $n\leq 1000$, the percentage of numbers of the form $p_n\cdot p_{n+k}$ which are jokers, with $k=2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ and $7$ is respectively $52 \%, 19.2 \%, 7.8 \%, 2 \%, 0.5 \%$ and $0.1 \%$.

Question : for any $k$, does there exist $n$ such that the number $p_n\cdot p_{n+k}$ is joker ?

Comment: Please put dollar signs around your maths, and use curly brackets for stuff in subscripts. Look up how to use Mathjax.

Comment: Unless there is something going on that I don't understand, it seems to me that $n=2p_m$ is always a joker number. $2$ is the smallest prime that divides $n$, and $p_m^2>2p_m \Rightarrow p_m> \sqrt{2p_m}$ so the largest prime $\le \sqrt{n}$ is also $2$. Since $m$ can be made as large as pleased, and the index of the prime $2$ is $1$, there should be a solution for every $k$

Comment: @KeithBackman $r(n)$ is the largest prime number less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$. It does not have to be a factor of $n$. For example, $r(10)=3>2=q(10)$, so $10$ is not joker.

Answer (score 2):

With PARI/GP, I could find examples upto $k=22$ , listed in the following output :

```
gp > for(s=2,25,z=primes(s);[a,b,c]=[z[1],nextprime(z[1]+1),z[s]];q=1;while(b^2<=a*c,q=q+1;a=b;b=nextprime(b+1);c=nextprime(c+1));print(s-1,"   ",q))
1   1
2   2
3   4
4   30
5   180
6   462
7   890
8   1532
9   3385
10   19871
11   29040
12   31545
13   31545
14   31545
15   597311
16   1293698
17   1293698
18   1293698
19   2279181
20   2279181
21   118374763
22   118374763
```

If the gap to the next prime is denoted with $a$ and the difference $p_{n+k}-p_n$ is denoted with $b$ , then $2a>b$ is sufficient for an example.

Considering that the merit of a prime gap defined as $$\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\ln(p_n)}$$ can be arbitarily large, such a solution should exist for arbitarily large $k$ , but this is of course no proof.

Note that a solution immediately implies that there is a solution for all smaller $k$ as well. So, chances are very good that the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Thanks a lot, Peter. I'm convinced that the answer is "yes" and I'm looking for proof. Your idea, may be, will help me.

Comment: It looks like other people have looked into this on OEIS (see [A230777](https://oeis.org/A230777) and [A228098](https://oeis.org/A228098)), but don't have as much data as you, so it would help if you update OEIS with your findings.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin ! I didn't know thos sequence on OEIS. So, there is no value > 14 in the 100000 first terms of A228098, and only one equals to 14: A228098(31545), which corresponds to prime(31545) = 370261. We coulld propose a conjecture like "If n is big, largesz

Comment: "If n is big, largest k is equivalent to ln(n) + ln(ln(n))... :)

Answer (score 0):

**NOT AN ANSWER. An extended discussion to restate the question being asked, which won't fit as a comment**

OP uses $n$ both as the name for joker numbers and as the primary index of primes. For clarity, I will avoid using $n$ as the primary index of primes.

A number $n$ with $3$ or more prime factors can have at most one prime factor larger than $\sqrt{n}$; if it had more than one such prime factor, their product alone would be greater than $n$. Thus if $n$ has $3$ or more prime factors, at least two of them must be smaller than $\sqrt{n}$. The only way that such a number might be a joker number is if the two prime factors $p_a$ smaller than $\sqrt{n}$ are equal: $n=(p_a)^2\cdot c$. Then $\sqrt{n}=p_a\sqrt{c}$ where $c$ has prime factors $\ge p_a$.

**Specific cases:** $p_a=c=2$ affords the noted exception $n=8$. $p_a=2,\ c=3 \Rightarrow n=12$, and $12$ is not a joker number by examination. $p_a\ge 3 \Rightarrow n\ge 27$, and since $27>25=p_{a+1}^2$, this affords no joker numbers. $c\ge 4 \Rightarrow p_a\sqrt{c}\ge 2p_a$ and by Bertrand's postulate, $p_a$ is not the smallest prime $\le \sqrt{n}$. Since $n$ has at least $2$, and (excepting $8$) cannot have $3$ or more prime factors, $n$ is a semiprime.

For any particular $p_a$, the joker numbers containing it as a prime factor lie within the interval $(p_a)^2$ to $(p_{a+1})^2$. OP's question can be stated: Let $k$ be the count of numbers in that interval that are products $p_ap_b$ such that $p_a<p_b<\frac{(p_{a+1})^2}{p_a}$; does there always exist $p_a$ such that $k$ can be arbitrarily large?

Let $p_{a+1}=p_a+g_a$, where $g_a$ is the gap between $p_a$ and $p_{a+1}$. Then acceptable $p_b$ to be counted are defined as $p_a<p_b<\frac{(p_{a}+g_a)^2}{p_a}=p_a+2g_a+\frac{g_a^2}{p_a}$. For sufficiently large $p_a$ we can consider $\frac{g_a^2}{p_a}$ to be an error term. We also know that there is only one prime to be counted within the interval from $p_a$ to $p_{a+1}$. So the question becomes: In the interval from $p_{a+1}$ to $p_{a+1}+g_a$, can there be arbitrarily many prime numbers?

At this time, I don't have an answer to that question.

Comment: As we can observe it, after a large interval we have not necessary only small intervals. But if we have it once a least, it could be sufficient.

Comment: @Denis I agree. Qualitatively, my discussion indicates that large values of $k$ arise when a large gap between primes is followed by relatively dense clusters of primes. But I can't find a quantitative expression that precisely describes that relationship.

Comment: thanks a lot and totally agree with you. It seems we don't know enough about prime numbers distribution

Comment: I also tried reasoning by the absurd but without result...